# mssql persist link go to stupid after physical re-connection db-link (php5-fpm/ mssql)

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

i do mssql_connect persist connection from php5-fpm proccess.

If physical connection to mssql db is go down then php proccess know it and show 'no connection' It's ok

But if in a next step physical connection is up then php process do not produce error and do not get right result. can freeze , or return mix chars (looks like a dump)

in a next step i do restart php5-fpm pool and it fix error.

i want to user persist connection how can i solve it? :)

ps. currently i use script in id-up.d folder and restart service if connection is up. but it is not well.

Comment: not only physical re-connect need for get this issue. restarting remote mssql will do same. seem s like pool bring to php process incorrect connection handle

Comment: Probably wrong implementation of database connection. Session end depends on your implementation.

Comment: php5 child process do not produce error :(, have idea how can i fix it ?